# How to override arithmetic operations on mixed torch.Tensor subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, pytorch

How can I control the behaviour of simple operations like `a + b`, `torch.sub(a, b)`, etc. when `a` and `b` are *different* subclasses of `torch.Tensor`?

I'd like to implement trivial `torch.Tensor` subclasses `Foo` and `Bar` and override their arithmetic operations to control the return type as follows:

```py
type(foo + bar) == Foo
type(torch.mul(foo, bar)) == Foo
type(bar + bar) == Bar
type(torch.div(bar, bar)) == Bar
```

`foo + foo` and `bar + bar` work as expected just by creating empty `torch.Tensor` subclasses.

```py
import torch

class Foo(torch.Tensor):
    pass

class Bar(torch.Tensor):
    pass

foo = Foo([1, 2, 3])
bar = Bar([4, 5, 6])
print(type(foo))  # __main__.Foo
print(foo + foo)  # tensor([2., 4., 6.])
print(type(foo + foo))  # __main__.Foo
print(torch.add(bar, bar))  # tensor([8., 10., 12.])
print(type(torch.add(bar, bar)))  # __main__.Bar
print(type(foo + torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])))  # __main__.Foo
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to implement custom behaviour for `foo + bar` or `torch.sub(foo, bar)`, and unfortunately the default behaviour is to raise an error, making my subclasses pretty useless.

```py
>>> foo + bar
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Foo' and 'Bar'
>>> torch.sub(foo, bar)
TypeError: no implementation found for 'torch.sub' on types that implement __torch_function__: [Foo, Bar]
```

The [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-torch-with-a-tensor-like-type) seem to indicate that I need to implement new functions the arithmetic functions I want to control and then dispatch them via `__torch_function__` in `Foo` and `Bar`. I find the docs light on detail about how to do this for `torch.Tensor` subclasses (as opposed to user-defined classes that contain a `torch.Tensor`) where the default `torch.add`/`torch.Tensor.add`/`torch.Tensor.__add__` eventually needs to be called, so my attempts have either resulted in recursion errors or fail to find the new functions I've implemented.

What would be a minimal implementation of `Foo`, `Bar`, and `add(a: Foo, b: Bar) -> Any` that would allow me to use `foo + bar` and `torch.add(foo, bar)` without raising errors?